# AWS CodeBuild as non-root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, yocto, bitbake, aws-codebuild

Is there a way to drop `root` user on **AWS CodeBuild**? 
We are building a Yocto project that fails on CodeBuild if we're root (Bitbake sanity check).

Our desperate approach doesn't work either:

```
...

build:
  commands:
    - chmod -R 777 $(pwd)/ && chown -R builder $(pwd)/ && su -c "$(pwd)/make.sh" -s /bin/bash builder
...
```

Fails with:

```
bash: /codebuild/output/src624711770/src/.../make.sh: Permission denied
```

Any idea how we could run this a non-root?

Comment: Not sure how running that command as `non-root` will fix `permission denied` problem as being `root` user gives you more permissions than `non-root` user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we ended up doing was the following:

Create a `Dockerfile` which contains all the stuff to build a Yocto / Bitbake project in which we `ADD` the required sources and create an user `builder` which we use to build our project.

```
  FROM ubuntu:16.04

  RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

  # Required Packages for the Host Development System
  RUN apt-get install -y gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib \
       build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect \
       xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping vim

  # Additional host packages required by poky/scripts/wic
  RUN apt-get install -y curl dosfstools mtools parted syslinux tree

  # Create a non-root user that will perform the actual build
  RUN id builder 2>/dev/null || useradd --uid 30000 --create-home builder
  RUN apt-get install -y sudo
  RUN echo "builder ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | tee -a /etc/sudoers

  # Fix error "Please use a locale setting which supports utf-8."
  # See https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/ResolvingLocaleIssues
  RUN apt-get install -y locales
  RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
          echo 'LANG="en_US.UTF-8"'>/etc/default/locale && \
          dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
          update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

  ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
  ENV LANG US.UTF-8
  ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8

  WORKDIR /home/builder/
  ADD ./ ./

  USER builder

  ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./make.sh"]
```

We build this docker during the Codebuild `pre_build` step and run the actual build in the `ENTRYPOINT` (in `make.sh`) when we run the image. After the container has been excited, we copy the `artifacts` to the Codebuild host and put them on S3:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - mkdir ./images
      - docker build -t bob .
  build:
    commands:
      - docker run bob:latest
  post_build:
    commands:
      # copy the last excited container's images into host as build artifact
      - docker cp $(docker container ls -a | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }'):/home/builder/yocto-env/build/tmp/deploy/images ./images
      - tar -cvzf artifacts.tar.gz ./images/*
artifacts:
  files:
    - artifacts.tar.gz
```

The only drawback this approach has, is the fact that we can't (easily) use Codebuild's caching functionality. But the build is sufficiently fast for us, since we do local builds during the day and basically one rebuild from scratch at night, which takes about 90 minutes (on the most powerful Codebuild instance).

Answer (score 9):

I am succeeded in using non-root user in AWS CodeBuild.
It takes much more than knowing some CodeBuild options to come up with a practical solution.

Everyone should spot `run-as` option [quite easily](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html).
The next question is "which user?"; you cannot just put any word as a username.

In order to find out which users are available, the next clue is at [Docker images provided by CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) section. There, you'll find a link to each image definition.
For me, the link leads me to [this page on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/tree/master/ubuntu/standard/4.0)
After inspecting the source code of `Dockerfile`, we'll know that there is a user called `codebuild-user` available. And we can use this `codebuild-user` for our `run-as` in the buildspec.

Then we'll face with a whole lot of other problems because the standard image only installs runtime of each language for `root` only.
This is as far as generic explanations can go.

For me, I wanted to use the Ruby runtime, so my only concern is the Ruby runtime.
If you use CodeBuild for something else, you are on your own now.

In order to utilize Ruby runtime as `codebuild-user`, we have to expose them from the root user. To do that, I change the required permissions and owner of `.rbenv` used by the CodeBuild image with the following command.

```sh
chmod +x ~
chown -R codebuild-user:codebuild-user ~/.rbenv
```

The `bundler` (Ruby's dependency management tool) still wants to access the home directory, which is not writable. We have to set up an environment variable to make it use other writable location as the home directory.
The environment variable is `BUNDLE_USER_HOME`.

Put everything together; my buildspec looks like:

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    RAILS_ENV: test
    BUNDLE_USER_HOME: /tmp/bundle-user
    BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING: true

run-as: codebuild-user

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      ruby: 2.x
    run-as: root
    commands:
      - chmod +x ~
      - chown -R codebuild-user:codebuild-user ~/.rbenv
      - bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'
      - bundle install
  build:
    commands:
      - bundle exec rails spec

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/bundle/**/*
```

My points are:

- It is, indeed, possible.
- Show how I did it for my use case.

Comment: mahn this needs to be documented properly

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for this feature request. Currently you cannot run as a non-root user in CodeBuild, I have passed it to the team for further review. Your feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this still the case? There's now a checkbox in the console...

Answer (score 4):

To run CodeBuild as non root you need to specify a Linux username using the run-as tag in your buildspec.yaml as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html)

```
version: 0.2

run-as: Linux-user-name

env:
  variables:
   key: "value"
   key: "value"
parameter-store:
key: "value"
key: "value"

phases:
  install:
  run-as: Linux-user-name
  runtime-versions:
    runtime: version
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `HOME` won't be set in the shell when you do this. If you need that set to the home directory of the `run-as` user, you must set it yourself, e.g., in the `env`/`variables` block.

Answer (score 3):

Sigh, so I came across this question and I am disappointed that there is no good or simple answer to this problem.  There are many, many processes that strongly discourage running as root like composer and others that will flat-out refuse like  wp-cli.  If you are using the Ubuntu "standard image" provided by AWS, then there appears to be an existing user in the /etc/passwd file, `dockremap:x:1000:1000::/home/dockremap:/bin/sh`.  I think this user is for userns-remap in docker and I am not sure about it's availability.  The other option that astonishingly hasn't been mentioned is running `useradd -N -G users develop` to create a new user in the container.  It is far simpler than spinning up a custom container for something so trivial.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, were you able to get it working with a `pre_build` command to add a user ?

Comment: I ended up running as root anyway before I quit trying to use CodeBuild.  This process is extremely painful and I have already wasted more time that I would ever hope to save by using these tools.  Do yourself a favor and use CircleCI or really anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62430568/152142), you can `run-as` the default CodeBuild user `codebuild-user`. To *create* a user see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76451104/152142).

In either case, to actually get things working:

- Set `run-as:` in specific phases, *not* globally, because root privileges are needed for e.g. the `install` phase.
- Add `export HOME=/home/codebuild-user` to each non-root phase. (CodeBuild's `run-as` doesn't set `$HOME` for you, it also seems to ignore/overwrite `env.variables.HOME`) :(
- Ensure the home dir exists: `mkdir ~codebuild-user`
- Ensure the non-root user has permissions to its home dir and the checkout dir: `chown -R codebuild-user:codebuild-user ~codebuild-user .`
- Ensure the non-root user can use `docker`: `chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Here's a skeleton of how I run CodeBuild jobs as an unprivileged user:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
    install:
        commands:
            # (install various things...)
            # ...
            #
            # Prepare env for unprivileged user.
            #
            - |
                mkdir -p ~codebuild-user
                chown -R codebuild-user:codebuild-user ~codebuild-user .
                chmod +x ~codebuild-user
                ls -ld ~codebuild-user
            # Ensure that the unprivileged user has permissions to the socket.
            - chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock

    pre_build:
        run-as: codebuild-user
        env:
            variables:
                HOME: /home/codebuild-user
        commands:
            # codebuild ignores the env.variables.HOME declaration above...?
            - export HOME=/home/codebuild-user
            # do stuff...

    build:
        run-as: codebuild-user
        env:
            variables:
                HOME: /home/codebuild-user
        commands:
            # codebuild ignores the env.variables.HOME declaration above...?
            - export HOME=/home/codebuild-user
            # do stuff...
            - npm ci
            - npm run test
```