# AWS CodeBuild by non-root user using `run-as` build spec

Tags: aws-codebuild

I would like to build with non-root user. To achieve this I'm looking at [run-as](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html) build spec.

> run-as: Optional sequence. Available to Linux users only. Specifies a Linux user that runs commands in this buildspec file. run-as grants the specified user read and execute permissions. When you specify run-as at the top of the buildspec file, it applies globally to all commands. If you don't want to specify a user for all buildspec file commands, you can specify one for commands in a phase by using run-as in one of the phases blocks. If run-as is not specified, then all commands run as the root.

1. How do I create the non-root user to put in `run-as`?
2. Where do I create that user?
3. What permissions I need to set since the cloned source files from git are owned by root?

Comment: Are you using the AWS provided CodeBuild docker images or using your own for your build environment?

Answer (score 3):

Go to [aws-codebuild-docker-images](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images), find the docker file for the environment image you are using, and in the docker file, you can see the user that is added to to build environement.

Im my case, I was using ubuntu/standard/3.0, so I could find the user [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/ubuntu/standard/3.0/Dockerfile#L55):

```
RUN useradd codebuild-user
```

So to switch to a non root user, you can do:

```
run-as: codebuild-user
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new user (on ubuntu-like Linux systems) the trick is to use `adduser --gecos GECOS --disabled-password ...`. Then you can `run-as` that user in specific phases.

Note that CodeBuild `run-as` does not set `$HOME` so you must explicitly set that.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - adduser --gecos GECOS --disabled-password test-user-1
      - adduser --gecos GECOS --disabled-password test-user-2
  build:
    run-as: test-user-1
    commands:
      - whoami
      - export HOME=/home/test-user-1
```

Or as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64224939/152142), CodeBuild provides a default non-root user named `codebuild-user`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76451161/152142

Answer (score -1):

You can define the linux user you want to run the build script in your buildspec.yml

```html
version: 0.2
run-as: Linux-user-name
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html